# Jquery can't check checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, onchange

Refer to this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FwSF3/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="password" id="Password" tabindex="2">
<input id="PasswordChk" type="checkbox" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#Password').on("keyup", function () {
    var password = $.trim($(this).val());    
    if(password.length == 0){
        $('#PasswordChk').removeAttr("checked");
    }else{
        $('#PasswordChk').attr("checked", "checked");
    }    
});
```

When I first type into the textbox, the checkbox is set.  When I remove the text (length = 0) it's unchecked.

However after unchecking, it can't re-check the checbox.

Anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Use .prop() instead of .attr() - read [prop vs attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

```
$('#Password').on("keyup", function () {
    var password = $.trim($(this).val());    
    $('#PasswordChk').prop("checked", password.length > 0);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hgmXy/)

Comment: Thanks, works great.  Do you know why my code doesn't work as expected though?

Comment: @TomGullen because you're removing the attribute when `password.length = 0`

Comment: @TomGullen also read the `Attributes vs. Properties` section under http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc and http://forum.jquery.com/topic/please-explain-attr-vs-prop-change-in-1-6